# Merging collection and sub collection observables in Angularfire2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

I have integrated stripe into my firebase project (Firestore) which through web hooks adds and updates the products I have setup in Stripe to the firestore database. To display available products I have an observable which is subscribed in the template using async pipe. This all works fine, however, each product document in the products collection has a sub collection called 'prices' which contains the current and previous prices. I am trying to figure out how to return this additional data for each product in the main products observable.

The code to return just the products is:

```
export interface Item { name: string; id: string; }

  watchProducts () {

      const productsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item> =
      this._firestore
      .collection('products', ref => {
        return ref.where('active', '==', true);
      });

      const currentProducts: Observable<Item[]> = productsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions => actions
          .map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data();
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            console.log('a.payload');
            console.log(a.payload);
            return { id, ...data };
          }),
        ),
      );
      return currentProducts;
  }
```

The template code is:

```
            <button *ngFor="let product of products | async" ">
                {{product.name}} £/ month
            </button>
```

The location of the prices collection is:

```
this._firestore
.collection('products')
.doc({productId})
.collection('prices', ref => {
        return ref.where('active', '==', true);
      })
```

I would like to merge the results so in the async ngFor I could access the current price with active === true. I've looked at switchMap and mergeMap but can't seem to get anything to work properly. My knowledge is RxJs is somewhat limited.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own `operator` as [Jeff introduced](https://fireship.io/lessons/firestore-joins-similar-to-sql/). But to simplify, you could manage it as following way:

```
const products$ = this._firestore
  .collection('products')
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    map((actions: any[]) => actions.map((a) => ({ ...a.payload.doc.data(), ...{ id: a.payload.doc.id } }))),
    switchMap((products: any[]) => {
      const pricesCols$ = products.map((p) =>
        this._firestore
          .collection(`products/${p.id}/prices`, (ref) => ref.where('active', '==', true))
          .valueChanges()
      );

      // passing the products value down the chain
      return combineLatest([of(products), combineLatest(pricesCols$.length ? pricesCols$ : [of([])])]);
    }),
    map(([products, pricesCols]) =>
      products.map((p, idx) => {
        p.prices = pricesCols[idx];
        return p;
      })
    )
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried implementing this and get an error of 'Type 'never' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.' for [products, pricesCols] and also 'Property 'map' does not exist on type 'never'.' on products.map. Any idea of why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: It is a linting error, you might give the types, for example: `switchMap((products)` to `switchMap((products: any[])`.

Comment: I updated the `code snippet` a little, let me know if you still see the problem.

Comment: Hi I've just updated my code and the problem still seems to be there.

Comment: My mistake, I was importing combineLatest from 'rxjs/operators' not 'rxjs'. Thanks for your help it works like a charm.

Comment: Out of interest (and to expand on the answer) how would I return a list of all prices from all products and have the associated parent product be listed within the individual prices.

Comment: Did this get resolved? I'm getting a list of products, but can't see the prices and no errors.
Trying:
Price: {{product.prices.unit_amount | currency}}

i've also tried Price: {{product.p.unit_amount | currency}} but this throws errors.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code from [coturiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9128086/coturiv), i modified the html to include the array from prices.

When i logged 'p' i could see everything i needed.

I also created a variable `products$` and changed the `const product$` to this.product$

That exposed `products$` in the DOM and the rest came easily.

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let product of products$ | async" class="my-card" fxLayoutWrap="wrap" fxLayout="column" fxFlex="90%" fxLayoutGap="16px">
    <img src="{{product.images[0]}}" height="200" alt="">
  <mat-card-title>{{product.name}}</mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-content>
    Description: {{product.description}}<br>

    Price: {{product.prices[0].unit_amount / 100 | currency}}
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-success">ADD TO CART</a>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

The key to getting the prices from the join was `product.prices[0].unit_amount / 100 | currency`

The Result...
[image]

Hope this helps.